# Retorno de falha no submit

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, ajax

Eu tenho um submit, que antes eu realizo esta função:

```
$('#modelEditar').submit(function (e) {
var cancelada = $("#Cancelada").val();
if (cancelada == "False") {
    e.preventDefault();
    var id = document.getElementById("nfseid").value;
    var valores = [];
    $('.item').each(function () {
        var entidade = {
            NFSeId: id,
            ProdutoId: parseInt($(this).children()[10].innerText),
            Id: parseInt($(this).children()[11].innerText),
            Codigo: ($(this).children()[1].innerText),
            Descricao: ($(this).children()[2].innerText),
            UnMedida: ($(this).children()[3].innerText),
            Qtd: ($(this).children()[4].innerText),
            ValorUnitário: parseFloat($(this).children()[5].innerText),
            Deducao: parseFloat($(this).children()[6].innerText),
            DescontoCondicionado: parseFloat($(this).children()[7].innerText),
            DescontoIncondicionado: parseFloat($(this).children()[8].innerText),
            ValorTotal: parseFloat($(this).children()[9].innerText),
        };
        valores.push(entidade);
    });
    var obj = {};
    obj.valores = valores;
    var form = this,
        $form = $(form);

    $.ajax({
        url: "/NFSe/SalvaNFSItens",
        type: 'POST',
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        data: JSON.stringify(obj),
        success: function (data) {
            if (data.sucesso == true) {
                if ($('#modelEditar').valid()) {
                    $form.off('submit').submit();
                    if (data.sucesso == false) {
                        console.log('entrou no falso');
                    }
                }
        }
    })
}
else {
    e.preventDefault();
    $("#mensagemalerta").html("NFSe já cancelada, não sendo possível a substituição/alteração.");
    $("#alerta").show();
    $("#alerta").fadeTo(3000, 500).slideUp(500, function () {
        $("#alerta").slideUp(500);
    });
}
})
```

Se retornar tudo ok, ele continua o submit, porém nos erros eu sempre retorno:

```
return Json(new { resultado = ViewData["Mensagem"], sucesso = false });
```

E ao tentar o submit ele aparece assim pra mim no formulário:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Eu queria tratar desta forma:

```
 if (data.sucesso == false)
{
    e.preventDefault();
    $("#mensagemalerta").html(data.resultado);
    $("#alerta").show();
    $("#alerta").fadeTo(3000, 500).slideUp(500, function () {
        $("#alerta").slideUp(500);
    });
}
```

Porém não estou sabendo como utilizar corretamente, para informar o erro dinamicamente para o usuário.

Comment: Tentou decodificar o JSON com `JSON.parse(data)` antes de acessar os valores?

Comment: Não, como posso fazer?

Comment: Adiciona esse trecho de código `data = JSON.parse(data)` antes de `if (data.sucesso == true)`

Comment: Eu tentei colocar aqui `if ($('#modelEditar').valid()) {
                        data = JSON.parse(data);
                        console.log(data);
                        //$form.off('submit').submit();

                    }` Porém ele esta retornando o erro Unexpected token o in JSON at position 1

Comment: Tem que ser no success

Comment: É pq eu tenho um retorno, e depois eu tenho outro, ai no `($('#modelEditar').valid())` eu tenho outro retorno, se eu colocar antes, sempre vai ser true, pois está pegando o primeiro, eu preciso do próximo retorno

Comment: Se não funcionar, remove esse código que eu falei e muda seu `dataType: "json"` pra maiúsculo, assim : `dataType: "JSON",`

Comment: Acho que entendi sua pergunta errado. Você já está pegando o valor corretamente com o JSON parseado... Qual o problema na verdade?

Answer (score 1):

Se eu entendi o que está acontecendo, a resposta do servidor é um JSON contendo a chave

```
{
  resultado: "Cógido: 0000 ... tente novamente", 
  sucesso: false
}
```

No seu trecho de código existe um erro lógico dentro da chave '*success*' na requisição AJAX, pois mesmo que a API retorne '*sucesso = false*', a **requisição não falhou**, então sugiro você fazer dessa forma:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "/NFSe/SalvaNFSItens",
    type: 'POST',
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    data: JSON.stringify(obj),
    success: function (data) {
        if (data.sucesso == true) {
            if ($('#modelEditar').valid()) {
                $form.off('submit').submit();
                if (data.sucesso == false) {
                    console.log('entrou no falso');
                }
            }
        } else {
            $("#mensagemalerta").html(data.resultado);
            $("#alerta").show();
            $("#alerta").fadeTo(3000, 500).slideUp(500, function () {
                $("#alerta").slideUp(500);
            });
        }
})
```